# Get the latest Changes from dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I'm developing dropbox image downloading application in android 
i have no idea how to identify dropbox image changes using [/delta](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta)  as mentioned in dropbox 
can you please give me any reference tutorials or any explanations specially what is cursor parameter and how to parse it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have did this as following way

```
DeltaPage<Entry> deltaPage;
String cursor =""; 
do {
   deltaPage = mApi.delta(cursor);
   cursor = deltaPage.cursor;
   if(..){
    ..
   }

} while (deltaPage.hasMore);
```

please note that "mApi" is a reference for "DropboxAPI"

to reach the answer I have used following links also 
[download dropbox api for android](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/android)  
 
documentation for delta in the Android Core SDK
[link 1](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#delta%28java.lang.String%29)

 [link 2](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.DeltaPage.html)

 [link 3](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.Entry.html)

 [how to use delta in general](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta)

when i was in trouble Mr.Gregory from Dropbox support has sent me these links and it was very helpful for me.. I hope they will hope you also..
cheers.. happy coding

Answer (score 2):

The first time you call delta, you don't pass a cursor. The response includes a cursor that you should use on your next call, and so-on.

Comment: thank you Mr smarx.. api also saying same as your answer. I need more  initiallly i have no idea how this is done. following I have made a answer with more explanation...